# Let user set a password for application, Android

Tags: android, android-activity, authentication

I want to let the user set a password for my Android app. 
So i want to show the Loginpage just once when the user 
starts the app and only if there is a password set.

My Problem is, when i start the Activity in onCreate() of the MainActivity
i won't be able to close the Loginpage because it will start again.
If i save a boolean in the Shared Preferences the Loginpage will not appear when the user starts the app again.
And i cannot set the loginscreen as the launching activity because the user should be able to decide whether he wants to set a password or not.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store also password in shared prefference, force user to not save blank, check lenght. if 0 show again login view, else authenticate with stored password or pass user to desired view.